# Disable access to specific folders for specific user in proftpd

Tags: proftpd

I'm running proftpd on my debian server, and all users are managed through ftpdb in mysql.
Currently i am trying to hide specific folders from specific user that i have.

I've tried to add the following to my proftpd conf file:

```
<Directory />
HideFiles (\-specific)$ 
</Directory>
```

and its hiding all folders that contain "-specific" in its name, but they are hidden from all users.
Any help will be well appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to limit the actions of a user is to use the Limit directive:

```
 <Directory /myfolder>
   <Limit DIRS>
      DenyUser bob
   </Limit>
 </Directory>
```

See more information on the [Limit](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html) and [Directory](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Directory.html) directives in the proftpd howto.